# Rule for FIELDS CANNOT TAKE ZERO AT ONCE

Tags: validation-rule

Validation Rule:

Both the fields should not be zero at once, if zero at once then error
message has to be displayed and if one field is zero and other field is
greater than zero then no error message.

Comment: Can you check if this works for you. `OR( AND(Number1__c ==0,Number2__c<1),AND(Number2__c ==0,Number1__c<1) )
`

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I am posting the same as answer as well.

Comment: Can you try this `OR( AND(Number1__c ==0,Number2__c<1),AND(Number2__c ==0,Number1__c<1) ,OR(Number1__c <0,Number2__c<0))`

Comment: Can you edit the question and post that condition as well.

Comment: Thanks @SaiPraveenKakkirala ,  now it is working perfectly.

Comment: Updated the answer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments please try the below validation rule.

```
 OR( AND(Number1__c ==0,Number2__c<1),AND(Number2__c ==0,Number1__c<1) ,OR(Number1__c <0,Number2__c<0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check if both fields are less than or equal to zero.

```
AND(FieldA__c <= 0, FieldB__c <= 0)
```

Remember, validation rules should return true when an error should be displayed.